# Do I need to create a module for a new program or just use an existing one?

Tags: selinux

We have been developing a program at work to be run on a CentOS image. This program is very critical for us, so we need it to run in a very secure context.

So, I was thinking of using SELinux to protect it. I have been reviewing the documentation around SELinux, however there is something that I am not sure I'm understanding. Do I need to create a new module specific for our custom program or can I use one of the existing ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an SELinux policy module for your program. You can't just take an existing one, because it'll mention paths to a different program, to different configuration files, to different data files, etc. But you can take an existing module for a program with similar requirements and adapt it. Don't forget to change the names for any types, attributes, etc. since using different names is what makes SELinux isolate programs.

Given the wording of your question, I'm not sure if you understand how SELinux works. Defining an SELinux module for your program primarily confines your program. It protects the rest of the system from your program, not the other way round. It's SELinux rules applying to other programs that protect your program's assets. Your policy module does protect your program inasmuch as it assigns a restrictive context to your program's *assets* (configuration and data files).